# How to make a dialog title right/left aligned

Tags: mfc, cwnd

With the help of `CWnd::SetWindowText` method, I am able to set the desired caption, to my dailog based application. How can I make it left/right aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To right-align dialog title, you need to set "Right Align Text" for the Dialog in the resource editor (corresponding extended style is WS_EX_RIGHT).

The WS_EX_LAYOUTRT style actually flips the dialog, so all controls are layed out from right-to-left. Title DOES get to the right, but the close button moves to the left. NOT what was asked in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

There are few extended window styles like `WS_EX_RIGHT` to do that.

Here is a sample:

```
int CTestAlignDlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | WS_EX_RTLREADING);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to edit .rc file for the same? Or using a method I need to change the style?

Comment: You can call `ModifyStyleEx` for this window to do that.

Comment: I tried something of this sort in rc file:

    STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |WS_EX_LEFT

and 

also tried:

    ModifyStyleEx(0,WS_EX_LEFT);

Both in vain

Comment: You might be interested in WS_EX_RTLREADING and WS_EX_LTRREADING styles.

Comment: Just wanted a sample on how to use it, because ModifyStyleEx(0,WS_EX_LEFT) or ModifyStyleEx(0,WS_EX_LTRREADING); doesnt seems to be working.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide you with code snippet

Comment: @Programmer: Both `WS_EX_LEFT` and `WS_EX_LTRREADING` have a value of `0x0`. So in other words, they are the default settings. Trying to remove those styles is futile. It just results in a no-op. You'll have to actually **add** the respective styles you want to use. Irrespective, all alignment styles are ignored unless you use a language that supports reading-order alignment (like Hebrew or Arabic).